# Harlem Shake javascript embedded in RSS…

Tags: javascript, rss

Is it possible to embed the [Harlem Shake javascript "exploit"](http://pastebin.com/YbnNuQuw) in an RSS feed? I am wondering (with my limited knowledge of both, and Google searches have been less than helpful) if one could sneakily craft an attack using their own RSS feed using the above javascript. If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed whatever HTML you like in an RSS feed.

HTML supports the `<script>` element for inline JavaScript.

So yes.

That said, consumers of RSS will often sanitise the HTML, so you can expect it to be filtered out before most people reading the RSS will see it. (Much like email clients that support HTML formatted email)